# Scriptless automount for systemd Linux systems

Tags: linux, systemd, automount, udev, hotswap

What is the proper way to do a **boot/hot-plug** automount for **ATA** and **USB** storage devices on **Linux** systems using **systemd** *without* requiring a GUI or a user having to be logged in?

It seems that calling `mount` from a *udev* rule is **[no longer acceptable](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1113720#p1113720)** with *systemd* (so [older rules](https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/auto-mounting-usb-storage/) are no longer guaranteed to work), and *udisks* does not automount if the user is not logged in locally.

The method should have a way to include ***mount options***, so writability and filesystem masks can be set, as well as clean up after an "ungraceful" unmount *(i.e., yanking the device out while still in use)*.

---

**NOTE:** Methods to accomplish this using **[shell scripts](https://serverfault.com/a/767079/297059)** have been discussed, but is there a way to do this without using scripts? *I want to stick to direct software capabilities as much as possible, although a script is acceptable if there is no other solution.*

---