# Automount ATA/SCSI drives with systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, scsi, automount, udev

I am attempting to automatically mount all **ATA/SCSI** drives on boot using `systemd` and `udev` *without* utilizing `/etc/fstab`.

This is necessary because filesystems need to be mounted on directories **named for their UUIDs**, and the drives are always being cold swapped for new drives, so constantly modifying `fstab` becomes tedious.

In order to do this, I used the following *script*, systemd *unit file*, and *udev rule* adapted from an [answer to a similar question for USB drives](https://serverfault.com/questions/766506/automount-usb-drives-with-systemd/767079).

However, while that answer works for USB drives, it ***does not work* for ATA/SCSI drives**: The script appears to execute successfully and create all necessary directories, but when boot up is complete, nothing is mounted. The script *does work* when run manually, however.

---

**/usr/local/bin/automount.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
ACTION=$1
DEVBASE=$2
DEVICE="/dev/${DEVBASE}"
SAVE="/root/${DEVBASE}"

# See if this drive is already mounted, and if so where
MOUNT_POINT=$(/bin/mount | /bin/grep ${DEVICE} | /usr/bin/awk '{ print $3 }')

do_mount()
{
    if [[ -n ${MOUNT_POINT} ]]
    then
        echo "Warning: ${DEVICE} is already mounted at ${MOUNT_POINT}"
        exit 1
    fi

    # Get info for this drive: $ID_FS_LABEL, $ID_FS_UUID, and $ID_FS_TYPE
    eval $(/sbin/blkid -o udev ${DEVICE})

    # Check if drive is already mounted / duplicate UUID
    LABEL=${ID_FS_UUID}
    /bin/grep -q " /media/${LABEL} " /etc/mtab \
        && ( echo "UUID ${LABEL} already in use"'!'; exit 1 )

    # Set mount point and save for later (in case of "yanked" unmount)
    MOUNT_POINT="/media/${LABEL}"
    echo "MOUNT_POINT=${MOUNT_POINT}" | /usr/bin/tee "${SAVE}"

    # Create mount point
    /bin/mkdir -p ${MOUNT_POINT}

    # Global mount options
    OPTS="rw,relatime"

    # File system type specific mount options
    case "${ID_FS_TYPE}" in
        vfat)
            OPTS+=",users,gid=100,umask=000,shortname=mixed,utf8=1,flush"
            ;;
    esac

    if ! /bin/mount -o ${OPTS} ${DEVICE} ${MOUNT_POINT}
    then
        echo "Error mounting ${DEVICE} (status = $?)"
        /bin/rmdir ${MOUNT_POINT}
        /bin/rm ${SAVE}
        exit 1
    fi

    echo "**** Mounted ${DEVICE} at ${MOUNT_POINT} ****"
}

do_unmount()
{
    eval $(/bin/cat "${SAVE}")

    [[ -z ${MOUNT_POINT} ]] \
        && ( echo "Warning: ${DEVICE} is not mounted"; exit 0)

    /bin/umount -l ${DEVICE} \
        && ( echo "**** Unmounted ${DEVICE}"; /bin/rm ${SAVE} ) \
        || ( echo "Unmounting ${DEVICE} failed"'!'; exit 1 )
}

case "${ACTION}" in
    add)
        do_mount
        ;;
    remove)
        do_unmount
        ;;
    *)
        echo "BAD OPTION ${ACTION}"'!'
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

**/etc/systemd/system/automount@.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Automount ATA/SCSI drive on %i

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/automount.sh add %i
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/automount.sh remove %i
```

**/etc/udev/rules.d/11-automount-ata-scsi.rules**:

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", SUBSYSTEMS!="scsi", GOTO="automount_ata_scsi_end"

ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/systemctl start automount@%k.service"

ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/systemctl stop automount@%k.service"

LABEL="automount_ata_scsi_end"
```

---

*(From the looks of it, ATA/SCSI drives actually do mount briefly with this setup, but then somehow unmount down the boot process.)*